# Same value numbering

Tags: sql-server

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE Numbering
(
    ID int, 
    Value nvarchar(100),
    ParentID int,
    Numbering int
)

INSERT INTO Numbering 
VALUES (1, 'Test1', 0, 0), (2, 'Test2', 0, 0), (3, 'Test3', 1, 0),
       (4, 'Test4', 1, 0), (5, 'Test5', 1, 0), (6, 'Test6', 1, 0),
       (7, 'Test7', 2, 0), (8, 'Test8', 2, 0), (9, 'Test9', 2, 0),
       (6, 'Test10', 2, 0)
```

I want to get same parent group numbering like this

```
ID     Value     ParentID     Numbering
----------------------------------------
1      Test1     0            1
2      Test2     0            2
3      test3     1            1
4      test4     1            2
5      test5     1            3
6      test6     1            4
7      test7     2            1
8      test8     2            2
9      test9     2            3
10     test10    2            4
```

Comment: `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY ID) AS Numbering FROM yourTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select 
  *, 
  row_number() over (partition by parentid order by id) as numbering 
from myTable
```